# Debian Linux: Start Nginx at rebooting machine

Tags: nginx, debian

I'm using Debian linux. I'm trying to make Nginx server to start automatically at reboot. By the way i can start and stop nginx like

```
$ /etc/init.d/nginx start
$ /etc/init.d/nginx stop
```

I googled and find that script must be added to update-rc.d so i did

```
$ /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f nginx defaults
```

but when i reboot nginx does not start my site gets bad gateway!

thnx in advance

Comment: What is in the error log?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the running processes and nginx log file to determine the cause of problem.
For example "Bad gateway" could mean that `nginx` is actually started but PHP5 backend (e.g. `php5-fpm`) is not running.